# Unable to set correct BodyPart header in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I have following scenario

```
exec(
        http("Request to endpoint: file")
          .post("http://localhost:8378/endpoint")
          .headers(Map(
            "Authorization" -> "Bearer ${access_token}"
          ))
          .bodyPart(StringBodyPart("text_param", "text_value"))
          .bodyPart(RawFileBodyPart("file", "image.png")
            .contentType("application/octet-stream")
            .header("content-length", "35260")
          ).asMultipartForm
          .check(status.is(200))
      )
```

And, I get following headers for 'file' body part

[image]

Expected: content-length => 35260

Actual: content-length35260

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just got the answer/workaroung: you need to add colon after **content-length**

.header("content-length:", "35260")

**UPDATE**: As it was mentioned by Stephane Landelle, CEO of Gatling Corporation, this is a bug of HttpAsyncClient

https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/issues/1168

So, in case u can update your dependencies -> use version of Gatling > 2.2.0. In other cases(I'm using 2.2.0 version), u can use it like I wrote.

Comment: No. That's a bug, not the way you're supposed to do this.

Comment: Sure. You created a pr, and this fix will be in next versions. For now, the option, that I've wrote, is one of the options, which is sending requests in the way it should. I will update my comment.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug in AsyncHttpClient: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/issues/1168

For the record, AHC 2.0.4 has been released with the fix.